# Spring AOP not working on HibernateDaoSupport getSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using spring AOP and I am able to pointcut openSession() method from  [SessionFactory()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html), but not able to do the same on getSession() from  [HibernateDaoSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html).

Am i correct in thinking that this difference in behaviour is due to getSession() is implemented in abstract class  and openSession() is in interface ?

Comment: Hi Gary. As I told you already in our chat, I can see several possible reasons why this could fail. I would love to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here: Java class(es) targeted by both aspects incl. annotations and package names, Spring configuration (especially, but not only AOP-related). Analysis is easier than guessing. :-) Thanks.

Comment: I will post MCVE soon, in meanwhile i generalized the question. See if you can help on this.

Comment: Then generalisation does not help as you removed rather than added detail. The answer depends on your configuration and code, otherwise I would not have asked for it.

Comment: Gary, with all due respect: You contacted me directly via WhatsApp because you did not even want to wait a single day for an answer to your question. So it seemed to be urgent. I responded, provided you with feedback here and there. So when will you feel inclined to post your MCVE? What is "soon" meant to be? If you expect such a high service level from someone helping you for free, why don't you speed up a bit as well?

Comment: Hi, I am extremely sorry. As you said it was definitely urgent and hence somehow i didn't got time for MCVE but i did some research and i found that using spring AOP we can't put aspect on protected methods implemented in a abstract class unless i guess if we are not using aspectj compiler hence i moved to different direction. Again apologies for the same.

Comment: Two things: Intercepting protected methods with Spring AOP is actually possible with CGLIB-based proxies, just not with JDK-based ones. And as an alternative, setting up AspectJ with load-time weaving (no compiler needed) is not difficult and well documented. So if you had just shared your MCVE, I might have been able to help you instead of you trying to find out everything on your own and believing you know when you actually just assume. ;-) Anyway, good luck.